MagnifyGesture not working in RealityView in SwiftUI
I am trying to implement a magnification gesture in a SwiftUI RealityView. My goal is to allow users to zoom into a RealityKit scene by pinching. However, the MagnifyGesture does not seem to have any effect. Below is my current implementation:
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var scale: Float = 1.0
    @GestureState private var magnifyBy = 1.0

    var magnification: some Gesture {
        MagnifyGesture()
            .targetedToAnyEntity()
            .updating($magnifyBy) { value, gestureState, transaction in
                gestureState = value.magnification
            }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            RealityView { content in
                // Load and Add Your RealityKit Scene (Without Anchor)
                if let sceneEntity = try? await Entity(named: "Scene", in: realityKitContentBundle) {
                    content.add(sceneEntity) // Directly add to content
                }
                
                // Add the initial RealityKit content
                let dataPoints = loadData()
                for dataPoint in dataPoints {
                    let sphere = createSphereEntity()
                    sphere.position = SIMD3(dataPoint.x, dataPoint.y, dataPoint.z)
                    content.add(sphere)
                }
            }
            .gesture(magnification)
            .scaleEffect(magnifyBy)

            // Display the current scale
            Text("Current Scale: \(magnifyBy, specifier: "%.2f")")
                .padding()
        }
    }

    func loadData() -> [SIMD3<Float>] {
        // Example function to load data points
        return [SIMD3(0, 0, 0), SIMD3(1, 1, 1)]
    }

    func createSphereEntity() -> Entity {
        // Example function to create a sphere entity
        return Entity()
    }
}

Issues:

The MagnifyGesture does not seem to affect the scale of the RealityView.
The scaleEffect(magnifyBy) modifier does not apply the magnification correctly.

Question:
How can I get the MagnifyGesture to work correctly within a RealityView in SwiftUI? Are there any specific considerations or additional steps needed to apply gestures to RealityView content?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
What did you try and what were you expecting?
I expected the MagnifyGesture to allow users to zoom into the RealityView content by pinching. I have tried:

Ensured that the RealityView and its content are properly set up and rendering correctly.
Applying the gesture to a 2D SwiftUI element like Circle(), which works correctly.

However, the magnification does not affect the RealityView. The magnifyBy state does not change when the gesture is applied to the RealityView, but it works as expected when applied to a 2D SwiftUI element like Circle().

Scaling 3D models using MagnifyGesture for RealityView


First Approach
If you want to implement a MagnifyGesture() to upscale / downscale 3D scene in RealityView, use the following approach. Note that I used a 25-cm-radius sphere created in Reality Composer Pro, that had neither InputTarget component nor collision shape (I assigned them programmatically). One important detail: if you move the model inside a RealityView using the sph.position.z property, the MagnifyGesture() will not work as expected! Instead, move the entire view using the offset(z:) modifier.
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
import RealityKitContent

struct ContentView : View {
    @GestureState var magnifyBy = 1.0
    @State var scale: Double = 1.0

    var magnification: some Gesture {
        MagnifyGesture(minimumScaleDelta: 0.001)
            .targetedToAnyEntity()
            .updating($magnifyBy) { (value, state, _) in
                Task {
                    scale *= value.magnification
                }
                state = scale
            }
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Scale: \(scale, specifier: "%.2f")")
                .font(.system(size: 200))
                .offset(y: 1000)
                .offset(z: -3000)

            RealityView { rvc in
                if let scene = try? await Entity(named: "Scene", in: rkcb) {
                    rvc.add(scene)
                    
                    let sph = scene.findEntity(named: "Sphere") as! ModelEntity
                    sph.scale *= 2.5
                    sph.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: false)
                    sph.components.set(InputTargetComponent())
                }
            }
            .gesture(magnification)
            .scaleEffect(scale)
            .offset(y: -1000)
            .offset(z: -4000)
        }
    }
}


@main struct ScalingApp : App {
    var body: some Scene {
        ImmersiveSpace() {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

Click these links to find out how to implement dragging and rotation gestures for RealityView.


Second Approach
I also want to introduce a second approach, which is quite different from the first one. But it's a little bit tricky. Note that I used a 70-cm-radius sphere here, from RCP, that does have InputTarget component and collision shape. Here's my code:
struct ContentView : View {
    @State var intermediateScale = 0.0
    @State var scale = 1.0

    var magnification: some Gesture {
        MagnifyGesture()
            .targetedToAnyEntity()
            .onChanged {
                intermediateScale = $0.magnification - 1.0
                scale += intermediateScale
                intermediateScale = 0.0
            }
    } 
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { rvc, attachments in
            if let model = try? await Entity(named: "Scene", in: rkcb),
               let text = attachments.entity(for: "attached") {
                model.position = [0, 1,-5]
                rvc.add(model)
                
                text.position = model.position
                text.position.y = model.position.y - 1.5
                rvc.add(text)
            }
        } update: { (rvc, _) in
            if let model = rvc.entities.first {                  
                let factor = Float(scale)
                model.scale = [factor, factor, factor]
            }
        } attachments: {
            Attachment(id: "attached") {
                Text("Scale: \(scale, specifier: "%.2f")")
                    .font(.system(size: 200))
            }
        }
        .gesture(magnification)
        .accessibilityZoomAction {
            if $0.direction == .zoomIn {
                scale += 0.01
            } else if $0.direction == .zoomOut {
                scale -= 0.01
            }
        }
    }
}


Looking forward to WWDC24 where RealityKit team will announce ScaleGesture3D.
